# Convergence/divergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove or disprove: The series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$$ converges.

I know its general term approaches zero. But I'm unsure to move further.

Can I have a hint?

Comment: Hint: What can you tell about $\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ and $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: @Jakobian: the first one diverges  whereas the second one converges. So..?

Comment: So suppose that the sum in question converges. Then the first one would be a difference of convergent series, hence convergent. Contradiction

Answer (score 3):

A series is convergent if and only if the limit of its partial sums is finite.

Write, for $k < \infty$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{1}{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\text{.}$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}  - \sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{1}{2n}\text{.}$$

---

**The proof**: 
Suppose by contradiction that 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$$
is finite.

We know that $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
is finite, hence 
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}  - \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} &= \lim_{k \to \infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} \right] \\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n-(-1)^n}{n} \\
&= \lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\dfrac{1}{2n}
\end{align}$$
will also be finite (because the sum of two finite real numbers is also finite), which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you sir...! for sharing your thoughts. This one helps too!

Answer (score 1):

The general term of your series is the sum of the general term of a divergent series and the general term of a convergent series. So your series diverges.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Let's prove that if the series $\sum a_n$ diverges and the series $\sum b_n$ converges, then the series $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ diverges. You have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k + b_k = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k + \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$$
so $(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k + b_k)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is the sum of a divergent sequence and a convergent sequence, so it's a divergent sequence. That means that the series $\sum a_n + b_n$ diverges.

Now you can apply this with $a_n = 1/(2n)$ and $b_n = (-1)^n/n$.

Comment: but in our case, both $a_n=1/2n$ and $b_n=(-1)^n/n$ are converges

Comment: @LDM $a_n$ is not convergent: it is proportional to the harmonic series $\sum 1/n$, which is not convergent as well, and multiplying a divergent series by a (nonzero) constant keeps it divergent.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that the sequence $\left( \sum_{k=1}^n 1/2k \right)$ diverges, whereas the sequence $\left( \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k/k \right)$ converges.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Super! now I understand